# jgrowl message is displayed unwantedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, jgrowl

```
try{

      myConnection.Open();
      SqlCommand myCommd = new SqlCommand(StrMemberId, myConnection);
      myCommd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberId", TxtEnterMemberId.Text);
        int value=(int)myCommd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (value!= 0 )
        {
            Response.Redirect("GeneralExamination.aspx? MemberId=" + this.TxtEnterMemberId);
        }

        else
        {
            string js = "$.jGrowl('  Invalid Member Id Try Again ');";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "jgrowlwarn", js, true);
            TxtEnterMemberId.Text = "";
        }


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally {
        myConnection.Close();
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do here is search a Member if does not exist or invalid input jgrowl will show a message(works fine).
i.) Now the problem is when i give the correct memberId a message is generated saying "thread was being aborted." but it does gets redirected to the destined page.What isthe exception about?

ii.) When i go to the next page and click on the back button.A msg box says"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier." if i click resend the growl is displayed again. How to deal with that?

Please help to overcome the problems..

Comment: @T.J. Crowder this may be a more useful link http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I) I think that the exception is for making a Response.Redirect inside a try/catch block, to avoid the exception you could add a false parameter to Redirect.

more info: [ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;312629)